# Simple proof that $\sup\{b^t : t \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ & }t≤x\} =\sup\{b^t : t \in \mathbb{Q}\text{ & }t<x\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Fix $b>1$. Let $B(x) = \{b^t : t \in \mathbb{Q}\text{ & }t≤x\}$ and let $B'(x) = \{b^t : t \in \mathbb{Q}\text{ & }t<x\}$.

Show that $\sup B(x) = \sup B'(x)$. It is quite easy to show the result holds for any irrational $x$. Yet I've been stuck for hours trying to prove it for rational $x$. It's also not difficult to show that $\sup B(x) ≥ \sup B'(x)$.

From here an idea would be to assume $ \alpha = \sup B(x) > \sup B'(x)$ and reach a contradiction. Which would be easy by finding $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $ \alpha < b^r < b^x$. The only problem is that I'm not allowed to use any material that isn't in the first chapter of Baby Rudin.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint; Stop problem 6 half way through.  Then do 7 a,b,c,d.  7d) will give you what you need.

Comment: I have trouble with this myself.  I'm not sure if I'm missing something or not, but for me this boiled down to showing there is no $(w, b^t)$ interval of real numbers with no $b^q$ in the interval (that's the only way the sup of $B'$ could be smaller than the sup of $B$). i.e. The is no interval with no rational power of $b$ in it.  I don't know if it didn't occur to Rudin that had to be proven or if I'm a dunce and am missing something.  I got around it by doing the first few parts of excercise 7.

Comment: @fleablood. You were right. The result follows immidiatly from applying 7d) to a rational. Thank you.

Comment: I'll be honest though.  I don't know what Rudin had in mind for us to do.  We need to prove that for a rational $x$ $b^x$ that there are $q < x$ that are arbitrarily so that $b^q < b^x$ that are arbitrarily close.  I don't see any way we can prove that without going ther the steps he does in excercise 7.  But we go into such detail in excercise 7 that either he has another way or it didn't occur to him it was an issue.  Oh, well.  We don't need 6c to do 7a,b,c, d (but we do for for 7 f,g) so we *can* do 6a,6b,7a,7b,7c,7d,6c, 6d,7e, 7f, 7g and be done with.

Answer (score 1):

If $\ x\ $ is rational, then $\ \sup B(x) = b^x\ $. If $\ \epsilon\ $ is any positive real number with $\ \epsilon < b^x\ $, let $\ d\ = \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{\epsilon}{b^x}\right)}-1 $, $\ q\ $ be an integer greater than $\ \frac{b}{d} $, and $\ t= x-\frac{1}{q}\ $.  Then  $\ \left(1 + d\right)^q \ge 1 +q\,d > b\ $, so $\ \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{\epsilon}{b^x}\right)}=1+d > b^\frac{1}{q}\ $.  Inverting this gives $b^{-1/q} > 1-\frac{\epsilon}{b^x}\ $.  Thus we have $\ b^t \in B'\left(x\right)\ $, $\ b^t = b^{x-\frac{1}{q}} > b^x - \epsilon\ $, and it follows that $\ \sup B'(x) > b^x - \epsilon\ $.  Since $\ \epsilon\ $ can be chosen arbitrarily close to $\ 0\ $, it follows that $\ \sup B'(x) \ge b^x $.

**Amendments and notes**

I have edited this proof to eliminate the use of logarithms, which a comment below informs us have not been covered at the point when the requested proof is asked for. There appear to me to be only two steps in the above proof that might be considered problematic:

- $\left(1 + d\,\right)^q \ge 1+q\ d\ $.  But even if the binomial theorem is considered off-limits for establishing this, it can still be proved easily enough by induction.
- That $\ 1+d > b^\frac{1}{q}\ $ follows from $\ \left(1 + d\right)^q > b\ $.  This follows, however, from its contrapositive, that if $\ 1+d \le b^\frac{1}{q}\ $, then $\ \left(1 + d\right)^q \le b^{\frac{1}{q}\,q} = b\ $.

Comment: In Rudin the real number $e$ is not introduced for many chapters and $\log_b$ is introduced in the excercise *immediately* following this

Comment: The very strange thing about these two excercise (Baby Rudin, 1.6 and 1.7) is that your addendum was was to be shown in the first half of excercise 7.  So Rudin *must* have had something else in mind for this problem 1.6, but dang if I know what it was.